# I mark error in line setOnRefreshListener

Tags: android

me marca este error The method setOnRefreshListener(PullToRefreshListView.OnRefreshListener) in the type PullToRefreshListView is not applicable for the arguments (activity)

my code is this

```
private class ListViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Context context = container.getContext();

        PullToRefreshListView plv = (PullToRefreshListView) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.layout_listview_in_viewpager, container, false);

        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                Arrays.asList(STRINGS));
        plv.setAdapter(adapter);

        plv.setOnRefreshListener(activity.this);

        // Now just add ListView to ViewPager and return it
        container.addView(plv, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        return plv;
    }
```

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung there's no logcat output. It's a compile time error

Comment: in setOnRefreshListener method, the parameter is interface OnRefreshListener. if your activity has implemented the interface, it should okay

Comment: public class activity extends Activity implements OnRefreshListener<ListView> {